# How do I search for values in a database using a value from a seperate database?

Tags: c#, web-applications

I'm making a system for checking bookings online using a booking ID, I've done all the code and when I run my application on the web browser it appears to disconnect with the message "Problem loading page"

this is the code used for checking the system when pressing the button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int custval = 70757;

    if (BookID.Text == Convert.ToString(custval))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection GuestBookings = new SqlConnection("Data Source=dell-vostro;Initial Catalog=HotelConference;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=website_application_testing;Password=***********");

            SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand();
            sc.Connection = GuestBookings;
            GuestBookings.Open();
            sc.CommandText = ("SELECT CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName FROM tblBookingGuests WHERE BookingID="+BookID.Text+")");
            sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GuestBookings.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions/errors?

Comment: for one thing your select has syntax error you dont need the closing bracket at the end - remove : ")"

Comment: What is the error exactly? Page can not load is not enough to diagnose.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I place the bracket at the end, however visual studio is throwing an error when I remove it, saying ')' Expected

Comment: @ReeceCottam your line should be : sc.CommandText = ("SELECT CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName FROM tblBookingGuests WHERE BookingID="+BookID.Text );

Comment: I'm not getting any errors or exceptions at all apart from that, and the webpage displayed a message saying "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading" but that's all I have

Comment: put a break point and see which line error occurs

Comment: Type `0; DELETE FROM tblBookingGuests; SELECT (1` in `BookID` when runnig your application, then read about SQL injection and start using parametrized queries.

Comment: I've edited the code and it does work @Sam, however the original issue is still happening

Comment: catch (Exception ex)
        {//print ex here
        }

Comment: @vikramBose I'm not sure how to display a message if the code throws an exception on c# web applications, also due to the current issue I don't believe it would display the said message anyway

Comment: ok, but Need to know what exception exact, So, If you have a logfilewriter in ur code?Use  try
 {
     ....
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     this.Session["exceptionMessage"] = ex.Message;
     Response.Redirect( "ErrorDisplay.aspx" );
     log.Write( ex.Message  + ex.StackTrace );
 }

Comment: Remove the "catch" statement - swallowing exceptions is evil.

Comment: or put a label in the Page and try this                                catch (YourException ex)
{
    errorLabel.Text = ex.Message;
    errorLabel.Visible = true;
}

Comment: Nevermind, a colleague resolved this issue with me, thanks for everyone's help =]

Comment: it turns out I needed to use LINQ